# How to get \include to clear a double page

Tags: include, etoolbox, patching

I write a `scrbook` (`twoside`) in which I `\include` files for every `section`. As I normally only want to print the pages for a single included file, I need to `\cleardoublepage` before (and potentially after) every `\include` to get the page numbering right.

My idea was to use `\apptocmd` (from the package `etoolbox`):

```
\apptocmd{\include}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
```

But while the `.log` file seems to tell that the patching worked, it has now effect.

```
[debug] tracing \apptocmd on input line 39
[debug] analyzing '\include'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro with parameters
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I would add the `\cleardoublepage` at the end of the included file. Then the empty page at the end belongs to the included file and not the master file and `\includeonly` works better.

Comment: Thanks @HeikoOberdiek! I modified my answer with an automated solution of your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\include` should not be modified, in my opinion, because its purpose is to check for nested `\include` (which is not allowed) and call, if the test is negative, to call `\@include`.

The `\@include` macro calls `\clearpage` twice, at the start and at the end. So what you seem to want is

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@include{\clearpage}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
\patchcmd\@include{\clearpage}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
\pretocmd{\include}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
```

does the job.

But following Heiko Oberdiek's advice (and IMO better still), one can also patch `\@include`:

```
\patchcmd{\@include}{\@input@ {#1.tex}\clearpage}{\@input@ {#1.tex}\cleardoublepage}{}{}
```

Comment: To avoid having an empty page at the end of the document because of the last included file: `\let\includeclearpage=\cleardoublepage \patchcmd{\@include}{\@input@ {#1.tex}{\clearpage}{\@input {#1.tex}\includecleardoublepage}{}{\errmessage{}}`. Then before the last `\include`:  `\let\includeclearpage=\clearpage \include{lastfile}`.